# Google Apps Marketplace set client ID and client secret of my app

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

Furthermore of OAuth2 "Service Account" where the Administrator need to grant the acces to the scopes.

Where could I set the "client ID and client secret" of my appengine app on Google Apps Marketplace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To set up your application ids you need to:

- Go to [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- Create a project.
- In 'Credentials' section you click on `Create New Client Id`button

Recommend watching the following - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxX4oNi_Uyc